# java how to execute method

Tags: java, class, methods

I have created a class Hotel defined as follows:

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Hotel {

  private Osoba[] tab = new Osoba[100];

  public void zamelduj(Osoba os, int num) {
    if (tab[num - 1] == null) {
      System.out.println("Pokoj o numerze " + num + "jest zajety");
      return;
    }
    tab[num - 1] = os;
  }

  public void wymelduj(int num) {
    tab[num - 1] = null;
  }

  public void zamienOsoby(int num1, int num2) {
    Osoba o = tab[num1 - 1];
    tab[num1 - 1] = tab[num2 - 1];
    tab[num2 - 1] = o;
  }

  public void znajdzWolnePokoje() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      if (tab[i] == null) System.out.println(i + 1);
    }
  }
  public void przydzielPokoje50() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      Random r = new Random();
      Osoba o = new Osoba();
      int num = r.nextInt(100);
      tab[num] = o;
    }
  }

  public void wypisz() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      if (tab[i] == null) System.out.println("Pokoj nr. " + (i + 1) + " jest wolny");
      else System.out.println("Pokoj nr. " + i + " jest zajety przez " + tab[i].imie + " " + tab[i].nazwisko);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hotel h = new Hotel();
    //h.przydzielPokoje50();
    //h.wypisz();
    h.zamelduj(null, 30);

  }

}
```

I also have a class Osoba:

```
public class Osoba {
  public String imie;
  public String nazwisko;

  Osoba() {
    imie = null;
    nazwisko = null;
  }

  Osoba(String imie, String nazwisko) {
    this.imie = imie;
    this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
  }
}
```

I want to execute the method Zamelduj, which will assign a person (Osoba) to a cell in a table. However, every time I insert something other than null in the following it says that the first argument is not a capable parameter of the method.

```
h.zamelduj(null, 30);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: not clear at all what are you asking

Comment: Exactly how to use this metod ... if you can insert code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that on the line " h.zamelduj(null, 30);" you need to create a new Osoba:

```
h.zamelduj(new Osoba("o.o", "._.!"), 30);
```

what happens is that the function is expecting a Osoba, if you give it another thing, it refuses. i hope it helps

Comment: unfortunately i get error saying "constructor Osoba(string,string) is undefined" ... should i make a constructor for it then?

Comment: That is the problem, you have a constructor for (string, string).. how you have your project setup? Is the 2 classes on the same file? are the classes in the same package?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object of the class hotel (in your class from where you want to call the method type):

```
Hotel myObjectHotel = new Hotel();
```

And then you can call the method trough:

```
myHotelObject. zamelduj(give parameters here);
```

:)

Update:
Missed the real question. Just focused on the topic. I'm sorry. ;)